# Is there a way to add handlebars to html.vim?

Tags: indentation, filetype-html

I'm working with handlebars right now and I'd like to get tags like:

```
{{#component 'whatever'}}

{{/component}}
```

and

```
{{#if}}

{{else}}

{{/if}}
```

to increase the indent count. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can add handlebars with `g:html_indent_tags` or `indentkeys`. Even Tim Pope's `ragtag` doesn't seem to support handlebars.

Does anyone know how I can add handlebars to html.vim so that they increase the indent count?

Thanks!

**Progress**

I'm hacking the html5.vim package to try to move this forward. I've gotten the increase in indentation working by adding these changes to `html5.vim/indent/html.vim`:

#### add the pattern to tags

```
call add(s:tags, 'view')
```

#### Modify HtmlIndentOpen Function

original:

```
" [-- count indent-increasing tags of line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentOpen(lnum, pattern)
    let s = substitute('x'.getline(a:lnum),
    \ '.\{-}\(\(<\)\('.a:pattern.'\)\>\)', "\1", 'g')
    let s = substitute(s, "[^\1].*$", '', '')
    return strlen(s)
endfun
```

modified:

```
" [-- count indent-increasing tags of line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentOpen(lnum, pattern)
    let s = substitute('x'.getline(a:lnum),
    \ '.\{-}\(\(<\|{{#\)\('.a:pattern.'\)\>\)', "\1", 'g')
    let s = substitute(s, "[^\1].*$", '', '')
    return strlen(s)
endfun
```

The only change is in the regex that `substitute` is using. I've changed the first group from `<` (i.e. match only an opening bracket) to `<\|{{#` (i.e. match an opening bracket or an opening handlebar expression).

And it works:

```
{{#view 'thing'}}
  stuff about things
  {{/view}}
```

The indentation gets increased on the `{{#view 'thing'}}` line. But, the closing tag `{{/view}}` isn't decreasing the indent count yet.

#### Modify HtmlIndentClose Function

original:

```
" [-- count indent-decreasing tags of line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentClose(lnum, pattern)
    let s = substitute('x'.getline(a:lnum),
    \ '.\{-}\(\(<\)/\('.a:pattern.'\)\>>\)', "\1", 'g')
    let s = substitute(s, "[^\1].*$", '', '')
    return strlen(s)
endfun
```

modified:

```
" [-- count indent-decreasing tags of line a:lnum --]
fun! <SID>HtmlIndentClose(lnum, pattern)
    let s = substitute('x'.getline(a:lnum),
    \ '.\{-}\(\(<\|{{\)/\('.a:pattern.'\)\>>\|}}\)', "\1", 'g')
    let s = substitute(s, "[^\1].*$", '', '')
    return strlen(s)
endfun
```

Basically, the original is looking for `a:pattern` inside of `</` and `>`. I've tried to modify it to look for `a:pattern` inside of `</` or `{{/` and `>` or `}}` but it's matching every handlebar expression (e.g. this regex is matching `{{outlet}}`).

Any help on figuring out the regex would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at the files in `$VIMRUNTIME/indent`.  They work by setting `indentexpr`.  Create a file for Handlebars that, err, handles the patterns you want, and return `HtmlIndent()` for everything else.

Comment: thanks @lcd047. That put me on the right track to get started hacking the vim-html5 plugin.